# Iterator for code that only takes a callback

Tags: c++, callback, iterator, c++17, legacy-code

I have a C library which I want to use in C++(17). The library internally backtracks over a complicated data structure, and once a candidate is found invokes a callback via

```
    CALLBACK(candidate);
```

`CALLBACK` is a macro and can be redefined at will, so that the user can now perform a calculation with the found `candidate`.

Instead of running my user code within `CALLBACK` directly, I want to add a layer of abstraction to the library to conform with STL data structures providing iterators. A forward iterator is sufficient for my purposes; this way I can use it at least in some of the STL algorithms demanding an iterator.

More specifically, I want an object `Library` that allows me to write

```
    for (auto it = Library.begin(); it != Library.end(); ++it) {
        const auto& candidate = *it;
        ...
    }
```

Is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

Merci!

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for here. Your pseudo-code looks like it's iterating through some data structure, and fetching a decomposable type, then... what? Do you want to do `CALLBACK` on that? Why can't you?

Comment: Hi Nicol, thanks for your reply!
Indeed, the library is iterating through a rather complicated data structure, and once an element within said structure has been found `CALLBACK` is run so that the user can do something with `arg1...arg3`.

I can provide `CALLBACK`, but I'd rather use the library as an iterator. The reason is that a lot of the STL algorithms require an iterator, and I'd like to keep that paradigm when working with said library.

I've amended my question slightly to make the wording more obvious.